# Warning: Undefined array key error in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, undefined

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>My First Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="form.php" method="get">
       Name: <input type="text" name="username">
        <br>
       Age: <input type="number" name="age"><br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

    <?php 
    echo $_GET["username"];
    echo "</br>";
    echo $_GET['age'];
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm getting an error:

> Warning: Undefined array key "username" in C:\Users\nambi\Desktop\PHP Tutorial\form.php on line 18

> Warning: Undefined array key "age" in C:\Users\nambi\Desktop\PHP Tutorial\form.php on line 20.

Comment: They are not set until you submit the form. Is that code in `form.php`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check first if the array key-value exists before you echo, like this:

```php
<?php
if (isset($_GET["username"], $_GET["age"])) {
    echo $_GET["username"];
    echo "</br>";
    echo $_GET['age'];
}
```

Comment: needs an isset for the $_GET['age'] too

Comment: That would still show a `Warning: Undefined array key "age" `

Comment: `array_key_exists(..)` requires two parameters

Comment: @brombeer he had isset() before the edit... that would do the trick :-)

Comment: Thx, was a bit to fast. Updatet my answer.

Comment: @GertB. Yep, but now it is `array_key_exists()` - which doesn't do the trick ;)

Comment: @GerarddeVisser I would use one if, so the unneeded <br> is removed too.

Comment: The difference between `isset` and `array_key_exists` is when a key exists with the value `null`, `isset` will return `false`, while `array_key_exists` will return `true`, so if the keys aren't set, before submit, both will return `false`

Comment: Thx. I've adjusted my answer according to your comments. Feel free to vote ;)

Comment: @sschwei1 using a form submit, the value will not be null

Comment: @GertB. exactly, so it doesn't matter whether to use `isset` or `array_key_exists`, or am I mistaken?

Comment: @sschwei1 nope, but the answer is edited, he used array_key_exists() with only one param. and before that one he had isset(), so went from a working answer to a php error. (mistakes can happen).

Comment: @GertB. Ahh ok, haven't seen the edit before

Comment: That's true. Didn't work after the first edit but works by now as answer is also accepted.